# Как получить подряд идущие цифры в списке

Tags: python

Есть список с цифрами. Если есть 2 и более подряд идущие цифры, то нужно из них оставить одну, при этом увеличив ее на число убранных.
Т.е. есть `[1, 2, 2, 5, 8, 8, 8]`. Из него должно получится `[1, 3, 5, 10]`.
Возможно ли реализовать такое?

Comment: @Эникейщик , трудность в том что не понятно. Есть какая-то функция или как это реализуется? Нужно просто пробегаться по списку каждый раз?

Comment: на такую специфическую задачу вряд ли есть какая-то функция. "Каждый раз" на обязательно, достаточно одного прохода.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Можно используя соответствующую функцию.

```
from itertools import groupby

a = [1, 2, 2, 5, 8, 8, 8, 7, 7, 1, 1, 1]

result = [k + len(list(g))-1 for k,g in groupby(a)]
print('>>>', result)
```

```
>>> [1, 3, 5, 10, 8, 3]
```

Если список считать закольцованным, то результат можно скорректировать:

```
if len(result) > 1 and a[0] == a[-1]:
    result[0] += result.pop() - a[0] + 1
```

```
>>> [4, 3, 5, 10, 8]
```

---

Вариант через генератор.

```
a = [1, 2, 2, 5, 8, 8, 8]

def get_compressed(lst):
    if lst: 
        si = 0
        for i, el in enumerate(lst):
            if el != lst[si]:
                yield lst[si] + i-si-1
                si = i
        yield lst[si] + i-si

result = list(get_compressed(a))
print('>>>', result)
```

```
>>> [1, 3, 5, 10]
```

Comment: выглядит по-питонски, век живи - век учись

Comment: `len(list(g))` можно заменить на `sum(1 for _ in g)`. К сожалению, в Питоне нет способа измерить длину `iterable`. Приходится выдумывать.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Можно, я знаю. Но это менее понятно, чем `len()`.

Answer (score 3):

Можно сделать так: проходимся по каждому элементу массива, при этом считая кол-во повторений. Если следующий элемент не равен текущему, то добавляем его в новый массив с определенным условием.

```
a = [1, 2, 2, 5, 8, 8, 8]

b = []
c = 0

for i in range(len(a)):
    if i < len(a) - 1 and a[i] == a[i + 1]:
        c += 1
    else:
        if c > 0:
            b.append(a[i - 1] + c)
            c = 0
        else: 
            b.append(a[i])
```

Comment: А зачем проверка i < len(a) - 1?

Comment: @Эникейщик, чтобы не выходить за границу массива

Comment: а как можно сделать так, что бы проверялись между собой первый и последний элемент массива? Просто отдельным условием?

Comment: @ZiEnTenIn, да. зачем?

Comment: @entithat надо. Спасибо)

Comment: @entithat По-идее, переменная `t` здесь вообще лишняя. Она всегда в момент использования равна `a[i]`, которую тоже можно использовать, т.к. она точно равна `a[i-1]` (что проверено на предыдущем шаге).

Comment: @entithat за тем, что нужно представит массив как круг. типо числа в конце и в начале массива тоже должны считаться как идущие подряд

Comment: @ZiEnTenIn Посмотрите в моём ответе пример кода как можно поправить результат для "закольцованного" списка.

Answer (score 1):

Через цикл, без импорта:

```py
def eat(data):
    data_it = iter(data)
    last = next(data_it)
    count = 0
    res = []
    for d in data_it:
        if last == d:
            count += 1
        else:
            res.append(last + count)
            count = 0
            last = d
    res.append(last + count)
    return res


a = [1, 2, 2, 5, 8, 8, 8]
print(eat(a))
# [1, 3, 5, 10]
```